# com+ application export problem. application proxy disabled

Tags: com+, mts

I have a com + application which I want to export as proxy.
The problem is that when I open the export wizard, the "Application proxy..." radio box is disabled.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your configuration is wrong. Change your application activation settings from "library" to "server application".

(Componente Services -> rightclick on your application -> Properties -> Activation)

Then it will work! :)